# Running a function and then running another function depending on the result of the 1st one

Tags: python

I have a piece of Python (2.7) code which connects to a mySQL DB and enters content from a csv file (DBCommit()). I want to clear the CSV (ClearCache()) file **ONLY** if the MySQL commit (DBCommit) is completed successfully. If it isn't (i.e. there was a problem with connection, or accepting the data etc) then the CSV is retained for processing later. Do I use, try, subprocess, threading or multi-threading?

BTW I'm a complete novice at coding! Any pointers would be great!

```
Code: 
*************************************

import subprocess, MySQLdb, os, sys, select, shutil

#***********************************
#Define Functions
#***********************************

#Cache file location - used as a transaction for the DB
CachePath = '/home/pi/GistCache.csv'

#Used as the initial log file. Another process writes to this file.
LogPath = '/home/pi/GistLog.csv'

#Connects to the DB and commits the CachePAth file to the MySQL DB
def DBCommit():
        cnx = MySQLdb.connect(user='user',passwd='password',host='ip',db='dbname')
        cur = cnx.cursor()
        DataImport = ("""LOAD DATA INFILE "/home/pi/GistCache.csv" INTO TABLE PI_GIST_LOG.PI_Gist_Log_Tbl COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (RFID,TimeStamp,MACAddr,IPAddr)""")
        cur.execute(DataImport)
        cnx.commit()
        cnx.close()

#opens the LogPath and Cache Path files, copys the content from LogPath to CachePath
def Append():
        with open(LogPath, "r") as logopen:
                next(logopen)
                for line in logopen:
                        with open(CachePath, "a") as cacheopen:
                                cacheopen.write(line)
#Creates a new LogPath File
def NewLogPath():
        with open(LogPath, 'w') as Log:
               Log.write("ID,RFID,TimeStamp,MAC,IP,\n")

#Deletes the LogPath and Creates a new version
def ClearLogPath():
        os.remove(LogPath)
        NewLogPath()

#deletes CachePath
def ClearCache():
        os.remove(CachePath)

#Reboots the PI
def Restart():
        command = "/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now"
        import subprocess
        process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = process.communicate()[0]
        print output

#*********************************
#Start Process
#*********************************

#checks if the CachePath file already exists - means the previous code failed to complete. If it does, then check LogPath. If that exists, then append the LogPath to CachePath, Clear log and upload to DB.
#If logPath doesn't exist, create it and reboot.

if os.path.lexists(CachePath):

        if os.path.lexists(LogPath):

                Append()
                ClearLogPath()
*********************
#This is what I want to run first DBConnect. 
                DBCommit()
#Only if DBconnect is successful, should it run ClearCache
                ClearCache()
*********************
        else:
                NewLogPath()
                Restart()

#If Cache doesn't exist, Check if LogPath exists. If it does, rename logpath to cachepath and recreate logpath. Commit to DB. Otherwise is LogPath doesn't exist, create it and reboot the PI

else:
        if os.path.lexists(LogPath):

                shutil.move(LogPath, CachePath)
                NewLogPath()
                DBCommit()
                ClearCache()
#If Cache and Log don't exist, recreate log and reboot
        else:
                NewLogPath()
                Restart()
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I can't see anything Raspberry Pi-specific in this question. Ok the other hand it's a clear cut programming question and should be rather asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry techraf - thanks for moving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use

```
if DBCommit():
    ## do stuff
```

If DBCommit returns anything (except 0, False, etc), it will be considered True, and do stuff.

And the negation: if not DBCommit()

**Your code:**

```
def DBCommit():
        cnx = MySQLdb.connect(user='user',passwd='password',host='ip',db='dbname')
        cur = cnx.cursor()
        DataImport = ("""LOAD DATA INFILE "/home/pi/GistCache.csv" INTO TABLE PI_GIST_LOG.PI_Gist_Log_Tbl COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (RFID,TimeStamp,MACAddr,IPAddr)""")
        cur.execute(DataImport)
        cnx.commit()
        cnx.close()
        return True

....

if os.path.lexists(CachePath):

        if os.path.lexists(LogPath):

                Append()
                ClearLogPath()
*********************
#This is what I want to run first DBConnect. 
                DBCommit()
#Only if DBconnect is successful, should it run ClearCache
                if DBCommit():
                     ClearCache()
*********************
        else:
                NewLogPath()
                Restart()
```

Comment: There is no `return` in `DBCommit()`, .i.e. its returns `None` which is always `False`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Didn't notice it.. I adjusted the code.

Comment: and the right way to handle failure in Python is exceptions, not returning error codes.

Comment: Thank you very much Anna Jeanine, I'll give that a test now.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Bruno, I think that is what I'm trying to achieve - no matter what the error is in the DBCommit, if one is thrown then the ClearCache doesn't run.

Comment: Thanks Anna, that seemed to do the trick. I disabled the mysql and the script left the cache file intact. Thanks :-)

Comment: No problem! Thank you for accepting the answer. Good luck coding!

Answer (score 0):

What happens with your current code if anything fails in the `DBCommit()` function ? I'm not going to try it by myself but chances are some exception will be raised, which *will* interrupt the program execution at this point, thus preventing  `ClearCache()` from being called. If you find out (after testing out all error conditions you can think of) that some possible errors in `DBCommit` do not raise an exception then you just have to handle these cases in `DBCommit` and make sure they DO raise an exception.

Comment: At the moment, it all works - but I'm only testing a small amount of data in the CSV file. I was worried that if the CSV was large, that the DBCommit could take a while to run and potentially error towards the end of the process, but the code would have already started processing the ClearCache. This could lead to a wiped Cache file, but the DBCommit was not finalised - meaning we could lose data.

Comment: I have no idea if this is how it works, but I was worried that this could happen so wanted to ensure that ClearCache doesn't run unless the DMCommit has completed without issues.